# Проблема с авторизацией вк

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, авторизация

Еще недавно перейдя на `oauth.vk.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=3682744&scope=5192863&v=3.0&response_type=token` и дав разрешения, можно было получить токен.

Сейчас же (с сегодняшнего утра), при попытке сделать это возвращается `{"error":"invalid_access","error_description":"Security issue"}`.

Если в scope не указывать messages всё работает как и должно(не относится к предыдущему способу получения токена).

Кроме того, старые токены, полученные с appId официального клиета вк, потеряли доступ к методам раздела messages.

Возможно это связанно с [этим](https://vk.com/dev/messages_api), однако другие неофициальные клиенты использующие авторизацию с теми же appId всё еще функционируют.

Как теперь можно реализовать прямую авторизацию и как  в принципе взаимодействовать с методами messages?

Мои боты написаны на python3, я использую [эту](https://github.com/voronind/vk/) или же [эту](https://github.com/python273/vk_api) библиотеку.

Вот результат попытки авторизации с их использованием

#### [vk](https://github.com/voronind/vk/):

#### CODE:

```
 androidAppId  = '2890984'
 api = vk.API(vk.AuthSession(androidAppId, login, password,
   scope='notify,friends,photos,email,audio,video,docs,notes,pages,
   status,offers,questions,wall,groups,messages,offline,notifications'))
```

#### ERROR:

```
2019-03-02 07:26:37,701 vk    utils:79 DEBUG: Response: 200 https://m.vk.com/
2019-03-02 07:26:37,702 vk    mixins:92 DEBUG: Cookies: <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie h=1 for .login.vk.com/>, <Cookie l=MY_VK_ID for .login.vk.com/>, <Cookie p=9961db467c0***27dd3 for .login.vk.com/>, <Cookie s=1 for .login.vk.com/>, <Cookie remixaudio_background_play_time_=0 for .vk.com/>, <Cookie remixaudio_background_play_time_limit=1800 for .vk.com/>, <Cookie remixaudio_date=02-03-2019 for .vk.com/>, <Cookie remixaudio_show_alert_today=0 for .vk.com/>, <Cookie remixlang=0 for .vk.com/>, <Cookie remixsid=4bf589bd9c4c133b***0831d9fdc3 for .vk.com/>, <Cookie remixstid=0_a4e***adc5 for .vk.com/>, <Cookie remixff=00 for m.vk.com/>]>
2019-03-02 07:26:37,707 vk    utils:77 DEBUG: Request: POST https://oauth.vk.com/authorize, params=None, data={'client_id': '2890984', 'display': 'mobile', 'response_type': 'token', 'scope': 'notify,friends,photos,email,audio,video,docs,notes,pages,status,offers,questions,wall,groups,messages,offline,notifications', 'v': '5.28'}
2019-03-02 07:26:37,850 vk    utils:79 DEBUG: Response: 200 https://oauth.vk.com/authorize
2019-03-02 07:26:37,851 vk    mixins:127 INFO: Getting permissions
2019-03-02 07:26:37,854 vk    mixins:130 DEBUG: Response form action: https://login.vk.com/?act=grant_access&client_id=2890984&settings=5192863&redirect_uri=&response_type=token&group_ids=&token_type=0&v=5.28&state=&display=mobile&ip_h=5113***66&hash=15515***f6c9561&https=1
2019-03-02 07:26:37,855 vk    utils:77 DEBUG: Request: GET https://login.vk.com/?act=grant_access&client_id=2890984&settings=5192863&redirect_uri=&response_type=token&group_ids=&token_type=0&v=5.28&state=&display=mobile&ip_h=51***166&hash=1***98_4***561&https=1, params=None, data=None
2019-03-02 07:26:37,920 vk    utils:79 DEBUG: Response: 401 https://oauth.vk.com/error?err=9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "path\to\vk\mixins.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.access_token = self.get_access_token()
  File "path\to\vk\mixins.py", line 75, in get_access_token
    raise VkAuthError('OAuth2 authorization error')
vk.exceptions.VkAuthError: OAuth2 authorization error
```

#### [vk_api](https://github.com/python273/vk_api):

#### CODE:

```
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi('+71234567890', 'mypassword')
vk_session.auth()
```

#### ERROR:

```
vk_api.exceptions.AuthError: API auth error: This application has no right to use messages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вконтакте ограничили доступ к API сообщений, подробнее https://vk.com/dev/messages_api
Тоже столкнулся с данной проблемой, решения пока нет...

Comment: Тоже уже нашел это, однако хочется понять как сторонние клиенты, например apidog.ru, всё еще работают. Видимо есть какое-то решение.

Comment: @SunnyCapt, для авторизации там используются данные официальных приложений (через Android/iPhone и т.п.).

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно убрать 'messages' из scope

```
import vk_api
vk = vk_api.VkApi(login='#',password='#', scope='wall, video')
vk.auth()
```

будут доступны методы 'wall, video'

Comment: Добавьте код, что бы ответ можно было считать полным

Comment: ответ, конечно, не удовлетворяет требованиям задающего вопрос. но мне помогло поднять мое приложение, которое не требовало работу с сообщениями

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно было использовать апи >= 5.0 версии

```bsh
curl -X GET 'https://oauth.vk.com/token?client_id=2274003&client_secret=<find_yourself>&scope=all&&v=5.1&grant_type=password&username=<login>&password=<password>'
```